# How do I use String.format()?

Tags: android, string-formatting

I have the following string in my resources:

`<string name="days_ago">%1$s days ago</string>`

I'm using it like so in my list adapter:

```
Long daysSincePost = hoursSincePost / 24;
String display = activity.getString(R.string.days_ago);
return String.format(display, Long.toString(daysSincePost));
```

I've verified that Long.toString() returns the correct value that I want to display.

The problem is that the value of `daysSincePost` never appears in my list view!  Instead, I get "`days ago`".

Am I using `String.format()` incorrectly?

I've tried using "`%1$d days ago`" and using the Long value directly, with no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
<string name="days_ago">%0$s days ago</string>
```

`Long.toString(daysSincePost)` has an index of '0' instead of '1'.